# Do I need ECC support on motherboard in order to use ECC RAM? (even without ECC functionality)

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have this board: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2960

I want to buy 16GB ram modules, but I found that ECC fully buffered modules are MORE CHEAP than non-ECC modules

ECC: http://www.ebay.com/itm/8GB-2X4GB-DDR2-MEMORY-RAM-PC2-5300-ECC-FULLY-BUFFERED-FBDIMM-DIMM-/350428630200 ($35)

NON-ECC: http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-8GB-2x4GB-PC2-6400-DDR2-800MHZ-240pin-DIMM-Memory-For-AMD-CPU-Motherboard-/291354329859 ($56)

Motherboard most likely doesn't support ECC, but I can live without it, question is, would these memories work at all?

Other question, the motherboard has intel CPU, but the other page says "Only support AMD CPU Chipset.Not work on All intel CPU chipset" that makes very little sense to me, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of RAM you linked to is **buffered** as well as ECC which means it definitely won't work. Buffered RAM is typically for servers so you need to make sure the RAM you buy is listed as unbuffered.

The second set of RAM doesn't look particularly good quality to me, and it does clearly say it's for AMD systems so I wouldn't risk buying it. You might be better of spending a bit more and getting something that is more likely to work properly, otherwise you could end up with a system that refuses to boot or blue-screens all the time.

You can use something like the [Crucial RAM finder](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for//ga-p43-es3g-%28rev*-1*0%29) to help determine more about the RAM your motherboard supports, they do also sell some RAM that is guaranteed to be compatible.